# Evaluate $\lim\limits_{x\to a} \left(f(x)/f(a)\right)^{1/(\log x-\log a)}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be differentiable at $x = a$ and let $f(a) > 0$. 
Evaluate:

$$\lim\limits_{x\to a} \left(\frac{f(x)}{f(a)}\right)^{\dfrac{1}{\log x-\log a}}$$

**My attempts:**
Let $$y=\lim\limits_{x\to a} \left(\frac{f(x)}{f(a)}\right)^{\dfrac{1}{\log x-\log a}}$$

Now I take log on both sides
\begin{align*}
\log y &= \log\left(\left(\frac{f(x)}{f(a)}\right)^{\dfrac{1}{\log x-\log a}}\right)\\
&= \frac{\log f(x) - \log f(a)}{x-a} \cdot \frac{x-a}{\log x-\log a}\\
&=  \frac{f'(a)}{f(a)}
\end{align*}

Therefore $$y= e^{\dfrac{f'(a)}{f(a)}}$$

Is my answer is correct or not? Please verify.

Comment: You also need $a>0$ so that $\log a$ makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost correct.

You forgot to add the part that
$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{x-a}{\log x-\log a}=a$$
so we get
$$\log y=\frac{af'(a)}{f(a)}$$
and thus
$$y=e^{\frac{af'(a)}{f(a)}}$$

Comment: im not getting,

Comment: @lomberlego In the end you only calculated $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{\log f(x) - \log f(a)}{x-a}$ but you need to calculate $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{\log f(x) - \log f(a)}{x-a} \cdot \frac{x-a}{\log x-\log a}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{\log f(x) - \log f(a)}{x-a} \cdot \lim_{x\to a}\frac{x-a}{\log x-\log a}$.

Comment: @ the Phenotype $$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{x-a}{\log x-\log a}=\frac{1}{f(a)}$$

Comment: $$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{x-a}{\log x-\log a}=\frac{1}{\lim_{x\to a}\frac{\log x-\log a}{x-a}}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{a}}=a$$

Comment: @lomberlego And because $$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{\log f(x)-\log f(a)}{x-a}=\frac{f'(a)}{f(a)}$$ due to the chain rule of calculating the derivative of $\log f(x)$ in $a$.

Comment: thanks a lots @Phenotype  ,,now i understands